# Package version creation failed Invalid type: EntitySubscription

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, sobject, tooling-api, patch

I am getting the below error when I am trying to create a patch version.

***Package version creation failed with an unknown error.  Invalid type: EntitySubscription.***

This Sobject is available in the previous release and the package creation worked fine. But during patch version creation it fails.

I am using the below command for package creation

sfdx force:package:beta:version:create -d force-app/main --wait 60 -x -c -f config/project-scratch-def.json

project-scratch-def.json

```
{
  "orgName": "Abcd",
  "edition": "Partner Developer",
  "language": "en_US",
  "hasSampleData": "true",
  "features": [
    "DebugApex",
    "StreamingAPI",
    "AnalyticsAdminPerms",
    "EventLogFile",
    "PlatformCache",
    "LightningSalesConsole"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "chatterSettings": {
      "enableChatter": true
    },
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "emailAdministrationSettings": {
      "enableEnhancedEmailEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```